# References and variable names in C++ - how do they work in regards to memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory, reference

This is a multi part question based on a project I'm currently undertaking. I will try to make it as brief as possible while still fully explaining the question, so sorry if this is a bit long.

1. When it comes to `std::vector`s in C++, how exactly do they work with variables? For example, if I have the following code:

```cpp
int myInt = 4;
std::vector<int> myIntVector;
myIntVector.push_back(myInt);
```

what happens? Does that area of memory inside `myIntVector` now have the same *value* of data stored inside `myInt` at the time of adding, but still completely separate them? Does the area of memory where `myInt` is stored get physically moved into a designated area inside of the memory of `myIntVector`?

2. Assuming I was correct on the last statement, why would `std::cout << myInt` still correctly print 4, assuming it was not changed, while `std::cout << myIntVector[0]` also prints out 4?
3. Now, for what prompted the question: the `#define` directive. I was experimenting with this for my project, and noticed something interesting. I used `#define GET_NAME(variable) (#variable)`, which returns the name of the inputted variable as a character array. If I were to have the following code:

```cpp
#define GET_NAME(variable) (#variable)

int myInt = 4;
std::vector<int> myIntVector;
myIntVector.push_back(myInt);

std::cout << GET_NAME(myInt) << "\n";
std::cout << GET_NAME(myIntVector[0]);
```

I would receive the following output:

```
myInt
myIntVector[0]
```

Why? Assuming the first statement from question 1 is correct, this is the expected output, but then we circle back to question 2. Assuming the second statement from question 2 is correct, this is the unintended output, as `myInt` or `myIntVector[0]` should be returned twice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read how macro substitution works in C++ first. As an example, why you need that, try `GET_NAME(noexistent_variable)` and explain the results.

Answer (score 3):

> When it comes to std::vectors in C++, how exactly do they work with variables?

All STL containers just copy values by default. So when you pass an `int` variable, it gets copied and the copy exist completely independently from the original value

> why would std::cout << myInt still correctly print 4, assuming it was not changed, while std::cout << myIntVector[0] also prints out 4?

These are two different values, both equal to 4

> If I were to have the following code, I would receive the following output. Why?

The macros just manipulate the text, and don't do anything fancy in your code. This statement:

```
std::cout << GET_NAME(myInt) << "\n";
```

Just turns into this under the macro:

```
std::cout << "myInt" << "\n";
```